Left Kan extension and finite product preserving
Let ${\rm Ani(Ring)}$ be the $\infty$-category of animated commutative rings, ${\rm Ani(Ring)^{\leq 0}}$ be the category of discrete animated rings and ${\rm Ani}$ be the $\infty$-category of spaces . Let $\mathcal F:{\rm Ani(Ring)^{\leq 0}}\to {\rm Ani}$ be an etale sheaf or more generally a finite product preserving functor. Does the left Kan extension of $\mathcal F$ along the inclusion ${\rm Ani(Ring)^{\leq 0}}\to {\rm Ani(Ring)}$ also preserve finite products?

Yes, but this is a completely general phenomenon unrelated to animated rings and sheaves. The general (surprising!) phenomenon is that the left Kan extension of any product preserving functor $C\to An$ along any functor $C\to D$ preserves finite products, as long as $C,D$ admit finite products - the functor $C\to D$ need not even preserve them.
When $C,D$ are small, you can prove this using the following characterization : a functor from a category with finite products to $An$ preserves finite products if and only if it is a sifted colimit of representables. Since this is an if-and-only-if and left Kan extension preserves colimits as well as representables, this proves the claim. In your situation, since everything is suitably accessible (even if $\mathcal F$ isn't), you can reduce to the small case.
But the proof in the general case surprisingly easy too : the key point is that the map $(C\times_D D_{/d_0}) \times (C \times_D D_{/d_1}) \to (C \times_D D_{/d_0 \times d_1})$ is a right adjoint and hence is cofinal. If you use this in the pointwise formula for left Kan extensions you'll get the result (there's a few details to check, in particular the map a priori goes in the wrong way, but things work out. I can add more details if needed)

Note to self — should compare to the 1-categorical literature on this topic — Borceux and Day, Karazeris and Protsonis.

@Maxime, pardon my naivety, but could you provide a reference for your statement "a functor from a category with finite products preserves finite products if and only if it is a sifted colimit of representables"? Thanks a lot!

@Mockingbird : I thought I could find it in HTT and it's almost there but not quite. Here's a proof sketch: in one direction, you "just" use that sifted colimits commute with products and that (co)representables presevre products; the other (more interesting) direction is the observation that for a product-preserving functor $F: C\to An$, the comma category $C_{/F}$ is sifted (this is an instructive exercise), and $F$ is the colimit over $c\in C_{/F}$  of $c$

Cool trick! And the same should be true if one replaces "finite products" with "finite limits", right? Just by running the same argument with filtered colimits instead of sifted colimits.

Also, does this work in an enriched context, i.e. where Ani is replaced by some presentable category $\mathcal V$? I am thinking about something along the lines of http://archive.numdam.org/item/CTGDC_1982__23_1_3_0.pdf, Theorem 6.12.

@W.Rether : yes to the first question. Wrt the enriched context, I'm not extremely familiar with Kelly's work, but it at least seems like the definition of "finite" therein would at least require some modification, but beyond that I don't see an obstruction to making something like this work (though I have not sat down with the details so I don't know how exactly to make it work)

@MaximeRamzi Thanks! Actually never mind the enrichment. I am more interested in a plain generalizarion from Ani to more general target categories, without requiring that C and D are enriched in those. I see how to generalize your argument to the case where Ani is replaced by an infinity topos, but not beyond. Maybe it's false in greater generality? Something related to failure of universality of colimits?

@W.Rether : I believe that for $E$ cocomplete and admitting finite products, the condition "the above result works for $E$" is equivalent to "in $E$, products commute with colimits in each variable". To see this, it is helpful to reformulate the latter as "for any small $E_0\subset E$ closed under finite products, the induced colimit-preserving functor $Psh(E_0)\to E$ preserves finite products". So it is related to universality of colimits, but not quite equivalent (since it only involves products and not pullbacks).

(I can add details about this equivalence if needed - though I suggest working it out; and also working out the analogue for filtered colimits and finite limits :) )
